# Assign string X to index of multidimensional data based on user directions.

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
grid = int(input("Grid size: "))

x = []
for i in range(grid):
  y = []
  for j in range(grid):
    e = '.'
    y.append(e)
  x.append(y)

x[0][0] = 'X'
for row in x:
  print(*row)

d = input("Direction: ")
```

I'm trying to work out how to assign X to the index of the grid position which the user input gives. Below is the question.

You're familiar with the story of Hansel and Gretel, so when you decide to go exploring you always make sure to keep track of where you've come from. Since you know how unreliable leaving a trail of breadcrumbs is, you decide to write a program to help you map out your trail.

Your program should first read in the size of the grid that you will be exploring, and then read in directions: left, right, up or down. You always start exploring at the top left of your map. After every step, you should print out the trail, reading in directions until a blank line is entered. You will never be directed off the edges of the map.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for someone to do your homework for you. Please show what you've actually tried...

Comment: Around here, posting your homework assignment verbatim isn't going to get you too far.